# How to embed BASH variable in MySQL query in shell script file

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, variables

```
#!/bin/bash
fut=$(date -d "+14 days" +'%Y-%m-%d')
echo $fut
mysql -u user -ppassword base1 << "EOF"
INSERT INTO tableB SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE startdate < $fut;
....many lines of MySQL....
EOF
```

Mysql engine doesn't understand `$fut` as a variable. What syntax should be applied to make this work?

Comment: Almost any dialect of SQL should have a way of generating a timestamp internally without needing to inject a value via the shell. In this case, `ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 14)` looks to be the necessary SQL code.

Answer (score 2):

I have no problem with using a here-document, but I would like to suggest another possibility which is slightly more verbose, but has advantages when you may have to do more than just substituting variables : piping the output of a function.

```
#!/bin/bash

sql_statement()
{
  local fut=$(date -d "+14 days" +'%Y-%m-%d')
  echo "INSERT INTO tableB SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE startdate < $fut;"
  echo "....many lines of MySQL...."
}

mysql -u user -ppassword base1 < <(sql_statement)
```

This is not required in this specific case, but allows the function to have additional logic (e.g. `if` blocks, loops...) to generate a more complex or variable SQL statement.  As a general solution, it has nice advantages.

Comment: The comment from Mark Reed about security applies here too, and is important to understand.  At some point, though, a system has to interact with data from outside, so at some point in the stack there has to be a competent programmer that controls or sanitizes the data being used, and a competent administrator that protects the system from being tampered with (because, in the end, if you don't trust your shell, your system utilities, your database engine not being infected or buggy, you can't really accomplish much).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `"` from the `EOF`:

```
#!/bin/bash
fut=$(date -d "+14 days" +'%Y-%m-%d')
echo $fut
mysql -u user -ppassword base1 << EOF
INSERT INTO tableB SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE startdate < $fut;
....many lines of MySQL....
EOF
```

From bash [docs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

> No parameter substitution when the "limit string" is quoted or escaped.

Comment: Any time you are doing simple string  substitution into an SQL query, you open up the possibility of injection attacks. In this case, the value of `$fut` is being set by the code, not an outside source, so the risk is negligible. But in general, you should consider using a language binding that lets you do prepared statements with parameter substitution handled at the MySQL tier. That includes Perl, Python, Ruby, any JVM language. In my opinion, interacting with an RDBMS is a good "time to move up from bash to something else" signpost.

Comment: Note that this differs from e.g. Perl, which respects the type of quotes: substitution within `<<"EOF"`, but not within `<<'EOF'`. The shell, on the other hand, turns off substitution with *any* quoting; even `<<\EOF` has that effect.